# (iphone) How to create UIImage from imageRef which is created in background thread?

Tags: iphone, background, uiimage

UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
can be done in main-thread only.. bah..

Now all my image create functions which are to be run in background thread has to be modified.
Question is how should I change the above line.

Usual steps of creating image were as below.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

CGContextRelease(context);

return img;
```

If performSelector returned a value, it would be rather easy.
But it's not. Since this seems rather common requirement, I wonder if there are preferable practice of doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
>   can be done in main-thread only.. bah..

Only if you want to target iOS 3.x devices. Starting from iOS 4, `UIImage` became thread-safe. If you need to run on iOS 3, typical behaviour would be to pass your CGImageRef back to the main thread, and have the `imageWithCGImage` method run there.

Comment: umm, Can you provide me on how to "pass CGImageRef back to main thread" so that "it can run imageWithCGImage"?  that was the question. Because strategy for doing this seems rather awkward.

Comment: Well, you'd use performSelector: `performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadImage:) withObject:(id)imageRef waitUntilDone:NO`. The only thing to notice is the (id) typecast. Not sure why you need performSelector to return a value, but you can use `waitUntilDone` to effectively get confirmation that a selector has completed. And you can always use `NSInvocation` if you need to do something more complicated.